# How soon will linux notice that a disk has been detached ? And can it be quicker?

Tags: linux, centos, disk, scsi

I found that if I detach a disk from my Linux server (CentOS 7), the related `/dev/sd*` file will disappear automatically about 10 seconds later.

I'm wondering how does Linux know a disk has been detached? Is there something like a sweeper keep scanning all the devices?

And is it possible to make this quicker?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks & https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delay is likely caused by `udisk2` & udev.

#### Research

```
$ ps -eaf|grep [u]disk
root     17041     1  0 09:48 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/udisks2/udisksd
```

Can query it for storage devices like so:

```
$ udisksctl status
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
VBOX HARDDISK             1.0       VBc5aaf476-f419b1f1  sda
```

If you look at the `udisk2` process:

```
$ lsof -p $(pidof udisksd) | tail
udisksd 17041 root    3u     unix 0xffff88003a49d400      0t0     611852 socket
udisksd 17041 root    4u  a_inode                0,9        0       4852 [eventfd]
udisksd 17041 root    5u  a_inode                0,9        0       4852 [eventfd]
udisksd 17041 root    6u     unix 0xffff88003a49c000      0t0     611853 socket
udisksd 17041 root    7u  a_inode                0,9        0       4852 [eventfd]
udisksd 17041 root    8r      REG                0,3        0     611907 /proc/17041/mountinfo
udisksd 17041 root    9r      REG                0,3        0 4026532019 /proc/swaps
udisksd 17041 root   10r  a_inode                0,9        0       4852 inotify
udisksd 17041 root   11u  netlink                         0t0     611910 KOBJECT_UEVENT
udisksd 17041 root   12u  a_inode                0,9        0       4852 [eventfd]
```

Not a lot to go on there, the thing that catches my eye there is `inotify`. Whenever I see that, I immediately think udev.

#### Looking for udev rules

```
$ find /etc/udev/rules.d/ /usr/lib/udev/rules.d  | grep sto
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
```

the 2nd file looks interesting, take a look inside. This line looks like the cause:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
...
# enable in-kernel media-presence polling
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="block", ATTR{parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs}=="0", ATTR{parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs}="2000"
```

> ATTR{parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs}=="0", 
>   ATTR{parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs}="2000"

#### References

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev#Waking_from_suspend_with_USB_device